# How can I remove nvidia drivers from software updater?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, update-manager

I have completely removed NVidia drivers from my laptop because it doesn't work correctly with my video card and switched to Intel graphics.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

However, during software update, I am always suggested to install nvidia dependencies again. How can I avoid it?

[image]

`dpkg -l | grep nvidia`  gives me related libraries which are left after uninstall:

```
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-390:amd64                             390.42-0ubuntu1+gpu18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library 
ii  libnvidia-common-390                                 390.48-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                     all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries 
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                          390.42-0ubuntu1+gpu18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package 
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:i386                           390.42-0ubuntu1+gpu18.04.1                     i386         NVIDIA libcompute package 
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:amd64                           390.42-0ubuntu1+gpu18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries 
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:i386                            390.42-0ubuntu1+gpu18.04.1                     i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries 
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:amd64                           390.42-0ubuntu1+gpu18.04.1                     amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library 
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:i386                            390.42-0ubuntu1+gpu18.04.1                     i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library 
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:amd64                             390.42-0ubuntu1+gpu18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library 
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386                              390.42-0ubuntu1+gpu18.04.1                     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library 
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:amd64                               390.42-0ubuntu1+gpu18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD 
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:i386                                390.42-0ubuntu1+gpu18.04.1                     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD 
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:amd64                             390.42-0ubuntu1+gpu18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library 
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386                              390.42-0ubuntu1+gpu18.04.1                     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library 
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390                        390.42-0ubuntu1+gpu18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Comment: How did you "removed NVidia drivers"? It looks like you didn't update the packaging system, which still thinks NVidia stuff is still installed, and needs updates.

Comment: I did it with sudo apt-get purge nvidia*, after that all the apps and ubuntu itself switched to intel graphic card.

Comment: What is output of this command `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` ?

Comment: @AliRazmdideh the output is added to the question

Comment: Run these commands to remove them `sudo apt purge libnvidia* xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` output some libraries of nvidia are not removed.

So run this command to purge them:

```
sudo apt purge libnvidia* xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390
```

And its also good to run `autoremove` to remove unnecessary packages:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: thanks! I did it and it almost solved the issue. However,  libnvidia-compute-390 is still here. It is shown in dpkg but cannot be removed with purge

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt purge  libnvidia-compute-390 ` command ?

Comment: Ok. that is it. I had to remove it with sudo apt remove libnvidia-compute-390:i386

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Comment: yes, thanks for help! Now all the dependencies are removed.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)